# Is it possible to set (add) custom properties to Qt widgets in QtCreator?

Tags: xml, qt, qt-creator

I want to convert the input of dialogues into xml.

The dialogues should be created in QtCreator. On commit I want to go through the object tree, and create similar xml from only those widgets, which are marked by a custom property as containing xml-value.

The tag name could be either the object name or the value of such a custom xml meta property.

So, is it possible in QtCreator to set any custom property in standard widgets?

Comment: I'm glad to know, I'm not the only one who have not noticed the "+"-Button :-). See the answer from Hamish Moffatt.

Comment: Combined with this answer, it allows you to replicate HTML CSS className behavior: https://forum.qt.io/topic/17237/using-css-class/3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a custom property to any widget, if that's what you mean. The Property Editor in Qt Designer has a "+" button which allows you to add a property. It'll ask you for its name and type, and once it's created you can set its value.

Comment: Yes, just what I wanted. So easy. I've always thought this button refers to the Filter. Is there also a way to add a dynamic property to a widget type, not only a particular instance? E.G. all QLineEdit should all display a custom property.